# perl: Why am I getting 404 in html response?

Tags: html, perl, url, http-status-code-404, cgi

I used Sublime Text 3 and xampp to write an html response perl cgi encountered error 404

The first page is index.html
URL: `http: // localhost / aa /`
Aa folder on xampp inside htdocs

```
<HTML>
<HEAD> <Title> CGI with lighttpd and Perl </ Title> </ HEAD>
<BODY>

<Form METHOD = GET ACTION = echo site_url ("C: \ xampp \ cgi-bin \ cgiDemo.pl")> <BR>
Class:

<INPUT type = radio name = class value = "3A"> 3A
<INPUT type = radio name = class value = "3B"> 3B
<P>
Input Your ID Here: <input type = "text" name = "studentID">
<BR>
Input Your Name Here: <input type = "text" name = "studentName">
<P>
<INPUT TYPE = submit VALUE = "Send"> <INPUT TYPE = reset VALUE = "Clear">
</ P>
</ Form>

</ BODY>
</ HTML>
```

The second page is cgiDemo.pl
URL: `http: // localhost / aa / echo? Class = 3A & studentID = & studentName =`
CgiDemo.pl is placed in xampp cgi-bin folder
Always show the requested url

```
#! "C: \ xampp \ perl \ bin \ perl.exe"

Print "Content-type: text / html \ n \ n";

Print "<html> <head> <title> HELLO! </ Title> </ head>";
Print "<body> \ n";
Print "<h2> CGI is working !!! </ h2> \ n";

# Print "String = $ ENV {'QUERY_STRING'} \ n \ n <p>";
@values ​​= split (/ & /, $ ENV {'QUERY_STRING'});
Foreach $ i (@values) {
($ Varname, $ mydata) = split (/ = /, $ i);
Print "$ varname = $ mydata \ n \ n <p>";
}
Print "</ body> </ html> \ n";
```

Which side is a problem
Thank you

Comment: If that is your real code, then there are a bunch of things wrong with it. For startes, you cannot put spaces between the sigil of a variable and the name. `$ mydata` is a syntax error. Start by putting `use strict` and `use warnings` on top of your script, and then fix the errors. Also I suggest you go and read your course material, because (no offence) it looks like you have no idea what you're doing. We can't teach you programming here, sorry.

Comment: Why so many extra spaces? Surely that's a copy-and-paste error?

Answer (score 0):

There are so many problems in your code. I'm not sure how you're attempting to learn Perl, but I think you need to put a little more effort in :-)

Your description isn't very clear, but I think you're saying that you get a 404 error when submitting the form in your HTML page. That almost certainly means that the "action" attribute on the form element contains an invalid URL. So let's start by looking at that line:

```
<Form METHOD = GET ACTION = echo site_url ("C: \ xampp \ cgi-bin \ cgiDemo.pl")>
```

As people have mentioned in the comments, there are too many spaces in this code. Hopefully that's a problem that has been added in the process of cutting the code from your machine to this site. So perhaps it really looks like this:

```
<Form METHOD="GET" ACTION='echo site_url ("C:\xampp\cgi-bin\cgiDemo.pl')>
```

Then there's that weird `echo site_url(...)` call. I'm not at all sure what technology that is - but you have a file path there, not a URL. I think it should be more like:

```
<Form METHOD="GET" ACTION="cgi-bin/cgiDemo.pl">
```

With changes along those lines, your CGI program should be found. You can then start to think about the many syntax errors in your Perl code.